# Fetching output to csv - python

Tags: python, scripting

I created a python script to test ping status of multiple servers through IP but I need to export to CSV in attached format. Can someone help on it.

```
with open('path_to_file/servers.json') as f:
    data=json.load(f)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  #Create a TCP/IP socket
for ip_address in data:

  rep=os.system('ping ' + ip_address)

  if rep == 0:
   print("Server %s is up" % ip_address)
  else:
   print("Server %s is down" % ip_address)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKFdw.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below program

```py
with open('path_to_file/servers.json') as f:
    data=json.load(f)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  #Create a TCP/IP socket
with open("output.csv","w") as f:
    f.write("IP address,status\n")
    for ip_address in data:
      rep=os.system('ping ' + ip_address)
      if rep == 0:
       f.write("%s,success\n" % ip_address)
      else:
       f.write("%s,failure\n" % ip_address)
```

Comment: Okay, you do not have to use csv module, but if not, I suggest that you use more modern string formatting rather than `%`.

Comment: Can you also help me on the below. I'm trying to get disk space details in csv but not sure how to get it in csv for multiple servers                                                                                                                                           with open('path_to_file/servers.json') as f:
    data=json.load(f)

with open("output.csv","w") as f:
     f.write("Total Space,Used Space,Free Space\n")


total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage("/")

totalspace = int(total // (2**30))

usedspace = int(used // (2**30))

freespace = int(free // (2**30))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `csv` module.

For example:

```
import os
import csv

data = ['127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.1']

with open('servers.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['IP address', 'Status'])
    
    for ip_address in data:
        
        rep = os.system('ping -c1 -w1 ' + ip_address)

        if rep == 0:
            status = 'success'
        else:
            status = 'failure'
        
        writer.writerow([ip_address, status])
```

giving:

```
IP address,Status
127.0.0.1,success
0.0.0.1,failure
```

Aside from the question about CSV, I added `ping` command line options `-c1` (send only one packet) and `-w1` (wait for up to one second) to what you were using, or it will not complete.  You might also want to suppress your `ping` terminal output, e.g. under Linux add `+ '> /dev/null'` in the `os.system` call.